# select properties of the vertice that has out with specified @rid

Tags: orientdb

here is the representation of my graph ( "()" for vertices,   "--->" for edges):

`(user1)--hasgroup->(friends)--hasuser->(user2)`

i have rid of user1 and user 2.
i wan't to retrieve properties of the group which has outE('hasuser') with user2

so i've tried:

```
for user1 @rid=#01:01
user2 @rid=#01:02
select out('hasgroup').name from #01:01 where out('hasuser') = #01:02
```

or like that:
    `select name from group where out('hasuser')=#01:02 and in('hasgroup') =#01:01`

i've tried many others but these seems the more logical to me(but anyway, it doesn't work at all....)

edit:
while i get the group's rid with `select shortestPath(#01:01, #01:02)[1]`, 
i have nothing with `select name from (SELECT shortestPath(#01:01, #01:02)[1])`

Comment: would you mind posting query for creating your (minimal) schema with some test data? I would be willing to test some things out, but i'm to lazy to setup database.

Answer (score 0):

i got it ! (partially...)
with traverse:

`select out.name, in from (traverse * from #01:01 while $depth <=3) where in=#01:02`

but i'm not able to replace the '*' with something more precise...
also i got it by testing many things and i don't really understand why #01:02 is an 'in' ?